# php unserialize values

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Values `$psabad1` is `(i:169;i:170;i:173)`; this is serialized. I want convert this value to `(169,170,173)`. In this code return just first value `(169)` while I want return all values `(169,170,173)`

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT `psabad`,`transId`,`pardakht` FROM `orders` WHERE      `transId`=?");
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $transId);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$stmt1->bind_result($psabad1, $transid1, $pardakht1);

while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
    $pardakht =  unserialize($psabad1);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT `idsabad`,`idmahsool`,sabad.tedad, sabad.pardakht, pack2.titr, pack2.brand FROM `sabad` INNER JOIN pack2 ON pack2.id = sabad.idmahsool WHERE `idsabad`=?");
    $stmt2->bind_param("i", $pardakht);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->store_result();
    $stmt2->bind_result($idsabad2, $idmahsool2,$tedad2, $pardakht2, $titr2, $brand2 );
    $stmt2->fetch();
    echo $titr2;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Could you rewrite your post, with a suggestive title and concise information?

Comment: Using English variable names will also help us understand your code better.

Comment: in this code print only value first $psabad1 while i want print all values in $psabad1

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks weird. Usually, serialize data looks like this :

```
a:9:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;i:8;i:9;}
```

If your data really looks as you say in your title, as $s below, you could be able to retrieve an array with this little function :

```
<?php

$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$s = 'i:1;i:2;i:3;i:4;i:5;i:6;i:7;i:8;i:9;';

var_dump($a === _unserialize($s));

function _unserialize($s){
    $i = 0;
    $_s = '';
    foreach(explode(';', trim($s, '()')) as $part){
        if($part != ''){
            $_s .= 'i:' . ($i++) . ';' . $part . ';';
        }
    }
    return unserialize('a:' . $i . ':{' . $_s . '}');
}
?>
```

Outputs :

```
..\php\php5.6\php.exe serialize.php
bool(true)
```

Comment: thank for answer bou i want $s = 'i:1;i:2;i:3;i:4;i:5;i:6;i:7;i:8;i:9;';  convert to $a=1,2,3,4,5,... and use Just one in ring while for example :   while($S.count){replace $r=a}

Comment: What about `implode(',' _unserialize($s))` or `foreach(_unserialize($s)...) `  from my example ?

Comment: your code return true or false but i want return all value in array value that's mean return 1,2,3,4,5,6 Separately

Comment: and values $s come from database

Comment: please answer this question

Comment: Oh wait...! I think I understand ! You got to `trim($s, '()')` as I editied. If not, _unserialize returns false if $s is not a "unserializable serializable" string. This means you example is not what I think it is.